# Write list of files into a js file using npm

Tags: file, npm, cross-platform, command-line-interface

I'd like to have a script for npm that did the following:

- Gets a list of files inside a folder (and subfolders)
- Write it into a JS file, with the following format:

  ```
  module.exports = [
    "folder/filename.png",
    "folder/subfolder/filename.png"
  ];
  ```

I'm currently doing it like this using the cli in Linux:

```
echo 'module.exports = [' | tee files.js && find . -name "*png" | sed s:"./":"  '": | sed s:".png":".png',": | tee files.js --append && echo '];' | tee files.js --append
```

Which is a bit contrived and not really cross platform. Are there any npm packages that provide similar functionality? I'm kinda lost on it.

Answer (score 0):

Well don't I feel silly. Had never used node directly but it was trivial to write a script to do this.

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

var fs = require('fs');
var list = [];

function traverse(folder) {
  var files = fs.readdirSync(folder);
  for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    if (files[i].indexOf('.png') > -1 || files[i].indexOf('.jpg') > -1) {
      list.push(folder + "/" + files[i]);
      console.log(i + folder + "/" + files[i]);
    } else {
      var path = folder + "/" + files[i];
      if (fs.lstatSync(path).isDirectory()) {
        traverse(path);
      }
    }
  }
}

function start() {
  traverse('./images');
  var string = "module.exports = [\n";
  for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    string += "  '" + list[i];
    if (list[i] !== list[list.length - 1]) {
      string += "',\n";
    } else {
      string += "'\n];"
    }
  }
  fs.writeFile("./src/assets.js", string, function (err) {
    if (err) {
      return console.log(err);
    }

    console.log("Assets file was updated!");
  });
}


start();
```